# Using a mysql_query result in another query

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Below are the queries I am executing. But for some reason $MachineQuery is not getting a result. I assume it has something to do with using $q1 in the query but I don't know why.
Any Ideas?

```
$q1 =mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT SymptomID
 FROM Tree
 WHERE SymptomID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT SymptomID
                         FROM  Tree
                         WHERE LBNodeID = 0 OR RBNodeID = 0)")

$MachineQuery = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT M.MachineID, M.MachineName
                                 FROM Machines M, Systems Sys, Symptoms Sym
                                 WHERE M.MachineID = Sys.MachineID AND Sys.SystemID  
                                 =Sym.SystemID AND Sym.SymptomID IN ($q1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `$q1` is a PHP resource.  It is not a query, an array, a string, or anything else.  As such, you need to "convert" the data to a type that is more usable by you.

Here is my solution:

```
$q1 =mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT SymptomID
    FROM Tree
    WHERE SymptomID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT SymptomID
                         FROM  Tree
                         WHERE LBNodeID = 0 OR RBNodeID = 0)");
$list = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q1)) {
    $list[] = $row[0];
}
$fullList = join(',', $list);

$MachineQuery = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT M.MachineID, M.MachineName
                                 FROM Machines M, Systems Sys, Symptoms Sym
                                 WHERE M.MachineID = Sys.MachineID AND Sys.SystemID  
                                 =Sym.SystemID AND Sym.SymptomID IN ($fullList)
```

That way you can reuse the results, and you don't have to run the query again.

Comment: That worked, just needed to turn the result column into an array. Thank all of you for your quick responses.

Answer (score 1):

$q1 is a MySQL resource variable, not a string or array. See the documentation for how to get the particular field(s) you want from that resource:

https://www.php.net/mysql_query

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0):

i'd try

```
$MachineQuery = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT M.MachineID, M.MachineName FROM Machines M, Systems Sys, Symptoms Sym WHERE M.MachineID = Sys.MachineID AND Sys.SystemID
=Sym.SystemID AND Sym.SymptomID IN (SELECT DISTINCT SymptomID FROM Tree WHERE SymptomID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT SymptomID FROM Tree WHERE LBNodeID = 0 OR RBNodeID = 0))
```

Comment: The problem is I use the result in multiple queries. So I would prefer not having to pull the same information multiple times.